# JMeter Summary report in distributed mode

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I am running Jmeter performance test in distributed mode (2 slaves + master). In my test script I have configured Summary 
Report which should save some data to csv file. 
This file location is configured with fixed name "reports/summary.csv" value.

When I connect successfully from master to both slaves, tests finish on slaves, but no data is returned to master directory "reports/summary.csv". When I was running setup with one slave and master, master was collecting this data. What could be the problem when I have 2 slaves? Name conflict maybe?

Answer (score 3):

Actually this problem was related to "jmeter-server" process not being able to connect to master using RMI. This network issue caused my jmeter-server to hang for decade on second node, and this stopped master node jmeter process from finnishing and finalizing results in mentioned summary file.

After I got it working, important thing to know is if you use SummaryReport or AggregateReport jMeter component in your testplan in distributed env., master will take care of collecting data from each slave.